# How to fix authStore on componentDidMount when redirected back from Cognito Sign In

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an issue when I redirected back from the Cognito login screen, my state doesn't change to true for Auth Users. The authStore only start working when I hard refresh the page. if I using React Routes I cannot change the state even though it doesn't refresh the authStore either.

My auth-store configuration file

```
import Amplify, { Auth, Hub } from 'aws-amplify';
import { awsConfig, signInUrl } from './auth-config';

class AuthStore {
  constructor(history) {
    this.history = history;
    console.log(this.history);
    this.registerHubListener();
    Amplify.configure(awsConfig);
  }

  subscribe = subscriber => {
    this.subscriber = subscriber;
  };

  unsubscribe = () => {
    this.subscriber = null;
  };

  notify = authenticated => {
    if (this.subscriber) this.subscriber(authenticated);
  };

  isAuthenticated = () => {
    return Boolean(Auth.userPool.getCurrentUser());
  };

  getCredentials = async () => {
    try {
      const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();
      this.notify(credentials.authenticated);
      return credentials;
    } catch (err) {
      this.notify(false);
    }
  };

  registerHubListener = () => {
    const self = this;
    const hubListener = {
      onHubCapsule: async capsule => {
        if (capsule.payload.event === 'configured') {
          self.notify(self.isAuthenticated());
        }
        if (capsule.payload.event === 'cognitoHostedUI') {
          self.notify(self.isAuthenticated());
          console.log('self.isAuthenticated()', self.isAuthenticated());
          self.history.push('/');
        }
      },
    };
    Hub.listen('auth', hubListener.onHubCapsule);
  };

  signIn = () => {
    window.location.assign(signInUrl);
  };

  signOut = async () => {
    try {
      await Auth.signOut();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
}

export default AuthStore;
```

and here is my simple React Component where I have an issue with

```
// @flow

import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  authStore: Object
}

type State = {
  authUser: boolean
}

class Component extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      authUser: this.props.authStore.isAuthenticated(),
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.authStore.subscribe(this.handleAuthChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.authStore.unsubscribe();
  }

  handleAuthChange = (authenticated) => {
    this.setState({ authUser: authenticated });
  };


  render() {
    const { authStore } = this.props;
    const { authUser } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={styles.headerMenu}>
         {console.log(authUser)}
         {authUser && (
              <button
                onClick={authStore.signOut}
                className={styles.headerUser}
              >
                log out
              </button>
            )}

            {!authUser && (
              <button
                onClick={authStore.signIn}
                className={styles.headerUser}
              >
                login
              </button>
            )}
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Component;
```